# Grass For Low-Maintenance Drainage Ditch in Austin Texas

Tags: lawn, grass, weed-control, drainage

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best grass to plant in a drainage ditch behind my house. Specifically, I'm looking for something that best meets the following criteria:

- **lowest maintenance possible: this is my biggest goal. The ditch has 45 degree slopes and fences on both sides so doing just about anything back there is a huge pain.**
- Drought tolerant: enough for Austin, Texas at least without irrigation since there is none in the ditch
- Doesn't get too unhappy with standing water for short-ish periods of time: if it rains for a couple days, there's usually a few days of standing water in the bottom couple inches of the ditch
- Doesn't mind a bit of shade: it's mostly sunny in the ditch, but there are fences on both the north and south sides so the parts against the south fence are often in shade for most/all of the day
- Doesn't require mowing often/at all
- Blocks out most/all weeds

I've done a bunch of goolging about it and narrowed it down to Centipedegrass or Buffalograss, but it doesn't seem like either of them are exactly what I'm looking for. So, I'd like to know if there's anything better out there that I've missed or if not, which of those two is a better option for this situation?

Thanks!

P.S. I don't particularly care about looks, so even a non "grass" plant/"weed" is acceptable too; I just need something that will keep the dirt from eroding, weeds from getting out of control, and the HOA from sending me nasty notices about it.

Comment: Gravel will meet all your requirements.